# How do I compute this gradient in TF 2.0?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, gradient, derivative

I am providing a minimal example of what I want to solve. I have defined a class and in that there are some variables defined across different functions. I want to know how to track those variables across functions to get the gradient. I think I have to use `tf.GradientTape` but I have tried some variants without success.

```
class A():
     def __init__(self):
         self.alpha = tf.Variable(2.0)
     def f1(self):
         wt = self.alpha * 5.0
         return wt
     def f2(self):
         wt_f1 = f1()
         with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            wt_f2 = wt_f1 * 10.0
            print(tape.gradient(wt_f2, self.alpha))

a = A()
print(a.f2())
```

The last line returns `None`. Clearly the derivative of `wt_f2` with respect to `alpha` is 50.0. However, I get `None`. Any idea? I tried initializing a persistent gradient tape in the `__init__` function and use that to watch variables such as `wt` and `self.alpha` but that didn't help. Any idea?

Update 1:

Putting `wt_f1` call under `tape` does not work .

```
class A():
     def __init__(self):
         self.alpha = tf.Variable(2.0)
     def f1(self):
         wt = self.alpha * 5.0
         return wt
     def f2(self):
         with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            wt_f1 = f1()
            wt_f2 = wt_f1 * 10.0
            print(tape.gradient(wt_f2, self.alpha))
```

This also returns `None`.

Comment: You need to put the `f1` call under the tape context as well.

Comment: @xdurch0 This didn't help, see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing None. Because `f2()` returns nothing, so you get `None`.
Remove print:

```
a = A()
a.f2()
```

Furthermore some edits may be good for your written code.

1. You missed the `self` before `f1()` function and this works because you have defined `f1` function somewhere else. Anyway add `self.f1()`.
2. Move `print` statement outside of `tape` scope. Because it's better to get gradient where recording is finished.
3. Add `tape.watch()` to ensure it is being traced by tape.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.alpha = tf.Variable(2.0)
    def f1(self):
        wt = self.alpha * 5.0
        return wt
    def f2(self):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            tape.watch(self.alpha)
            wt_f1 = self.f1()
            wt_f2 = wt_f1 * 10.0
        print(tape.gradient(wt_f2, self.alpha))
```

Comment: Ah, I knew I was missing something simple :). Thanks.